# MYSQL- get different length substring

Tags: mysql

In my table I have a text column which contains data in format i.e:

```
["Name",100,500]
["Long Name", 8,0]
["Very Long Name",5000,1000]
```

I want to select first parameter from these string using only SQL queries. Is any way I can do that? I want to see as a result

```
Name
Long Name
Very Long Name
etc.
```

I know I could select all rows, then in PHP decode it to array and display, but I want also be able to do different operations using only mysql, like group by Name.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT REPLACE( SUBSTRING_INDEX( <column_name>, '"', 2), '["', '' )
FROM <table_name>
```

Where `<column_name>` is the column's name and `<table_name>` is the table's name.

**What this code does:**

1. `SUBSTRING_INDEX( <column_name>, '"', 2)` returns everything before the second double quotes, for example: ["Long Name
2. Replaces `["` by an empty string on the result above.